# .NET 4.0 application throws exception on a machine without Visual Studio

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

My application works great on all computers here that has Visual Studio installed, but it does not work on the machine that does not have Visual Studio.

The application just crashes on start up with this message in the Event Viewer:

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(System.String[])
at IssueTrackingSystem.My.MyApplication.Main(System.String[])
```

I tested a simple application with just one button, same results.

[image: Error]

UPDATE:

[image: New error]

Comment: Do the target machines have .NET 4 installed?

Comment: Add a `catch` block and check the `InnerException`.

Comment: Also, make sure that the target machine has the full .NET 4, not just the ".NET 4 Client Profile," if your application needs it.

Comment: How do you deploy the application to the machine that does not have VS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to get the exception's InnerException to really know what is going wrong. Project + Properties, Application tab, click the View Application Events button.  In the upper left combobox above the editor window select "(MyApplication Events)", in the right combobox select "Startup".

That adds the Startup event handler.  Make it look similar to this:

```
    Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf KaboomHandler
    End Sub

    Private Sub KaboomHandler(sender As Object, e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        MsgBox(e.ExceptionObject.ToString())
        Environment.Exit(1)
    End Sub
```

You'll now get a stack trace that includes the inner exception.  That should be good enough to find the static constructor that bombs.  Post the stack trace you see in your question if that doesn't help.

Comment: Looks to me that you didn't deploy the correct version of the DevExpress components you use.

Answer (score 5):

A `System.TypeInitializationException` will be thrown when a constructor for any type throws an exception that is not caught and handled appropriately.  Static initialization of fields will also throw this exception.  You will need to determine which type it is and debug accordingly.  Most likely, as other posters have said, you don't have something configured/deployed on the target machine.

I've seen this happen when trying to access config file entries that don't exist, when libraries weren't present, etc.  Until you get the detailed exception (you should be able to examine the inner exception), it will be more difficult to narrow down.

**UPDATE:**

Try this in your app.config as the article in the error message suggests:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check the .NET version installed on the client machine.
Also check all referenced assemblies, and if there is some unusual, add them to the `.bin` folder

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure the DevXpress assemblies are properly deployed.
Also, the error message instructs you to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191568(VS.100).aspx. Did you do this?

Comment: Yes I did. I followed the instructions and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I previously posted this [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29549414/4512948) and I'm going to link it here since it showed up on my Google search results.

A summary of it:

It turns out that for a project with the Target Framework as .NET 4.0 or .NET 4.0 CP, there are some DLLs that do not exist in .NET 4.5, in my project's case Visual Basic DLLs.

My project was a Visual Basic (VB6) project upgraded to Visual Basic .NET (VB.net) and it somehow needed the DLL called  `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll` located in

`C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VBPowerPacks\v10.0`

The InstallShield project that packages the files into the installer also fails to detect this dependency.

I only found this out after realizing that the Project runs fine with Visual Studio installed, but crashes with no specific warning other than 'System.IOException.FileNotFound' in the crash log.