# WPF Application crashes on second system without a session of visual studio running

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

We have a WPF application built in Visual Studio built in system A.  It runs out of VS on system A (as well as in VS, obviously).  But when I take the .exe to a second system (B) and run it there it crashes before it comes up.  It puts up the infamous message: "xxx has stopped working, Windows is checking for a solution to the problem".  Of course, Windows never finds a solution.  But it runs if I have Visual Studio running on system B (even though it's a new session with no connection whatsoever to the application).  This has me scratching my head.  I have already tried everything in this thread: [Application crash without Visual Studio installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240409/application-crash-without-visual-studio-installed)

I was absolutely sure the part about 'disable the option "Enable Visual Studio hosting process"' would solve the problem but it didn't.  I have disabled that option in the project settings for all instances and it still crashes.  Any ideas?  Sorry if I can't share the code.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Event Viewer for additional details regarding the crash?

Comment: What version of .net are you targeting. Does this version exist on the system experiencing the crash? Are you referencing GAC assemblies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can be lots of reason. first you have to check window  Event Viewer, you will able to find actual reason.

also you should handle  DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException". this will show actual error.

in App.XAML :

```
DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException"
```

and in App.cs:

```
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks JRB for your suggestion.  The unhandled exception handling didn't alleviate the problem.  Looking at the Windows log event viewer for applications I see that the event it's complaining about is of type "CLR20r3".  Here is the full text:

Comment: 3996068370 
   5 
   CLR20r3 
   Not available 
   -257729962 
   xversx.exe 
   1.0.0.0 
   5289b8b0 
   PresentationFramework 
   3.0.0.0 
   4f7d47f1 
   6259 
   e1 
   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse

Comment: check this link may help.  http://cdn.community-tracker.com/permalinks/11697/coverartconfig-error

Comment: means your XAML is breaking . so check statiresource those are added but unable to find. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2a1e0040-98a8-44f2-a1d3-380af8d15cc7/getting-systemwindowsmarkupxamlparse-when-running-application-exe?forum=wpf

Comment: Using the above as my starting point I was eventually able to get a traceback to where the problem was happening and from there it was much easier to come up with a solution.  I added the following try/catch to the main portion of my code, look at the event log afterward to find the traceback there.  Thanks JRB.

Comment: Try {..}  catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string SourceName = "WindowsService.ExceptionLog";
                if (!EventLog.SourceExists(SourceName))
                {
                    EventLog.CreateEventSource(SourceName, "Application");
                }

                EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
                eventLog.Source = SourceName;
                string message = string.Format("MyException: {0} \n\nStack: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                eventLog.WriteEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }